# an exetension of Doob's inequality

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Doob's inequality gives an estimation of

$$\mathbb{P}(\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}|X_t|\geq\varepsilon)$$

where $X$ is a martingale. Now I wonder how to estimate

$$\mathbb{P}(\sup_{0\leq t,s\leq 1, |t-s|\leq\delta}|X_t-X_s|\geq\varepsilon)\ \ (\ast)$$

If $L^1$ integrability is not enough for the estimation, we can add some assumptions about the integrability of $X$. Does someon have an idea for this estimation of $(\ast)$? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is $X$ supposed to have cadlag/continuous sample paths?

Comment: yes, $X$ is a continuous martingale

Comment: Do you need the inequality in this generality or do you have a specific application in mind?

Comment: Generally, I have an estimation:

Comment: $$\mathbb{P}(\sup_{0\leq t,s\leq 1, |t-s|\leq\delta}|X_t-X_s|\geq3\epsilon)\leq\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{P}(\sup_{t_{i-1} \leq t\leq t_i}|X_t-X_{t_{i-1}}|\geq\epsilon)$$

Comment: where $(t_i)_{0\leq i\leq n}$ is a division of $[0,1]$ with $t_i-t_{i-1}\geq\delta$

Comment: But this estimation is not precise enough for my application. Now what is known it that $X$ is continuous martingale and the marginal distribution of $X$: under $\mathbb{P}$, $X_t$ has a distribution $\mu_t$.

Comment: So if we denote by $\mathcal{P}$ the set of all probability measures $\mathbb{P}$ under which $X$ is a martingale and with margina distribution $\mu$, how can we prove(or adding some additional conditions on $\mu$) that $forall\epsilon>0$, we have

Comment: $$\sup_{\mathbb{P}\in\mathcal{P}}\mathbb{P}(\sup_{0\leq t,s\leq 1, |t-s|\leq\delta}|X_t-X_s|\geq\varepsilon)\rightarrow 0,\ \ \delta\rightarrow 0$$